# Assigining value to the Select tag's value property in React js

Tags: reactjs, react-select

This is the code for my select tag:

```
let defaultValue = _.find(item.value,{InsCoverageID:item.defaultValue});

<Select
  options={item.value.map(obj=>({label:obj.Coverage,value:obj.InsCoverageID}))}
  value={{value:defaultValue.InsCoverageID,label:defaultValue.Coverage}}
  name={item.name}
  onChange={(e)=>_onChangeGlobal({name:item.name,value:e.value,event:e.label})}
  required={item.required}
  disabled={item.disable}
/>
```

Here the property, `value` has to assigned according to a condition , ie

- If `defaultValue` has value then  `value={{value:defaultValue.InsCoverageID,label:defaultValue.Coverage}}`
- If there is no value in `defaultValue` then  `value={item.value.map(obj=>({label:obj.Coverage,value:obj.InsCoverageID}))}`

How can I implement these two conditions to the `value` property of select tag?

Answer (score 0):

just use if else:

```
let defaultValue = _.find(item.value,{InsCoverageID:item.defaultValue});

<Select
  options={item.value.map(obj=>({label:obj.Coverage,value:obj.InsCoverageID}))}
  value={defaultValue?{value:defaultValue.InsCoverageID,label:defaultValue.Coverage}
  :item.value.map(obj=>({label:obj.Coverage,value:obj.InsCoverageID}))
  }
  name={item.name}
  onChange={(e)=>_onChangeGlobal({name:item.name,value:e.value,event:e.label})}
  required={item.required}
  disabled={item.disable}
/>
```